# Current hovered column of my table is a little wider than others

Tags: css, layout, hover

I have a table where I set a kind of button on mouseover the cell. Then problem is that when I move between columns, we can see the current column a little more wide than others. Difficult to explain.

Here is a little video of demonstration: http://screencast.com/t/WbHIlSHim

How can we avoid it?

Here is my css

```
#MatrixTable td
{
    padding: 0px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;    
}

#MatrixTable:hover
{
    cursor: default;
}

#MatrixTable td a:hover
{
    cursor: none;
}

#MatrixTable td:first-child
{
    padding-left: 5px;
    text-align:left; 
}

#MatrixTable td a
{
    padding: 8px 10px;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Thanks.

---

UPDATE

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q35f7/

Comment: This isn't all of your CSS. Either that or there is JS in effect as well. Please post all of the relevant code and a live demo on http://jsfiddle.net/, if possible

Comment: Sorry. I created a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q35f7/ this is not exactly the same but the problem is reproduced. I would like to avoid columns to be expanded when mouseover. Thanks.

Comment: When you hover the button, the CSS changes. I can't read minified CSS easily, but basically strip down the CSS to the smallest piece of code that exhibits the problem. I'm pretty sure it's either a font sizing issue or a padding/margin issue.

Comment: @bronzato check this http://jsfiddle.net/Nuv6C/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, most generally it's because the CSS changed when you added the new class, adding a whole lot of other stuff. The offending changes that created the size change were `padding`, `border` and a few others, which will always alter the size of the object.

For example, if you added `.class:hover{border: 500px solid #000;}` on mousover, that element would get a heck of a lot bigger when you hovered over it. A similar effect would happen if you did `.class:hover{padding:9999px;}`. See what I'm getting at here?

I've edited it for you removing the style rules that would create the "annoying" size change:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q35f7/1/